# Flower/Plant Identification

Tags: species-identification, flowers, freshwater-biology, flowering

Could anyone please identify this flower/plant found on the semi-shaded banks of a river in East Ireland? It was located near [Japanese Knotweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallopia_japonica) and looks quite similar to this.

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [Himalayan balsam (*Impatiens glandulifera*).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impatiens_glandulifera?wprov=sfsi1)

> Tall, stems often reddish. Lvs opposite or in threes, with small red teeth. Fls large, pale to dark pink-purple, with short bent spur; July-Oct. Bare places, especially by streams.

The Wild Flowers of Britain and Northern Europe. Fitter, Fitter, Blamey. 1974. Collins, London.

Comment: We have a species of impatiens in the US called Jewelweed. Those seedpods when ripe are fun for kids: they pop suddenly on handling, scattering their seeds. :) The sap is a nice topical anti-itch field remedy for mosquito bites, poison ivy, etc.

Comment: Yes, jewelweed is mentioned as an alternative name on the WP page. It is considered to be an invasive weed in the U.K. because it can take over riverside land.

Comment: Yes, definitely invasive on this certain riverside.